# execute sql returned in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that runs against a sql server database that produces a sql statement for each row of the query returned.

EG.

```
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.[Proc1]
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.[Proc2]
```

etc

In the same script, how can I execute the sql returned in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dump the results into a variable of type varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) and then EXEC them

```
-- Create a terrible, horrible cursor to run the statements
-- You have just now killed a kitten
DECLARE Csr cursor for
SELECT
    P.name AS proc_name
,   schema_name(P.schema_id) AS schemaname
FROM
    sys.procedures P


DECLARE @query varchar(max), @proc_name sysname, @schema sysname

OPEN Csr
FETCH NEXT FROM Csr INTO
    @proc_name, @schema

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            -- build out the drop statement, may not be necc
            SET @query = 'DROP PROCEDURE' + QUOTENAME(@schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@proc_name)
            -- Actually run the dynamic query
            EXECUTE(@query)
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            -- Be good and note what failed, fix this manually
            PRINT 'This query failed'
            PRINT @query
        END CATCH
        FETCH NEXT FROM Csr INTO
            @proc_name, @schema
    END
END

CLOSE Csr
DEALLOCATE Csr
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

One way is, you'll have to iterate through your result set and use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). Just curious though, what are you  trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is have your query output into a variable.  If you are using a stored procedure, then specify an output paramater of varchar.  Then when you call the stored procedure to generate the SQL query just pass that varchar variable to `sp_executesql`.